# What could make a form field "un-focus-able"?

Tags: html, forms

I have a form, and for some reason I cannot "click into" some of the fields, although I can tab through them.  This behaviour was not always there as I was building the (somewhat complex) form, but it has crept in now and I am not sure what to look for to troubleshoot.

Can anyone tell me what conditions could occur to make a form field un-selectable?

EDIT - people have asked for the code, so here it is.  (Although I thought it would be nice to have a list of possible troublemakers/troubleshooting for future generations...)

So as I have this up in my browser right now, I cant click into anything past "inspiration".  I know I have a UL inside a UL there, but it is inside an LI so as I have read, that is valid.  And even if it wasn't it should only affect validation, correct?  This "freezing up" thing seems strange behaviour.

```
<form name="thumbnail" id="signup-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="x1" value="" id="x1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="y1" value="" id="y1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="x2" value="" id="x2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="y2" value="" id="y2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="w" value="" id="w" />
    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="" id="h" />
    <fieldset class="password">
    <legend>Please Choose a password so you can access your profile in the future</legend>

    <div class="row">
    <label for="password1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" size="20" id="password1" name="password1" class="required"/>

    <div id="passwordStrengthDiv" class="is0"></div></div>

    <div class="row"><label for="password2">Password Again</label>
        <input type="password" size="20" id="password2" name="password2" class="required"/></div>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset class="basicInfo">
        <legend>Basic Info </legend>

        <ul>
            <li><label for="firstName">First Name</label><input type="text" size="20" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="" class="required"/></li>
            <li><label for="lastName">Last Name</label><input type="text" size="20" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="" class="required"/></li>
        </ul>

    </fieldset><!-- close basicInfo -->

    <div class="margin-div"><textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="desc_short" class="required">Short description</textarea></div>


    <fieldset class="moreInfo">
        <legend>More Info</legend>


        <li><label for="nationality">Nationality</label><input type="text" size="20" id="nationality" name="nationality" class="required"/></li>
        <li><label for="speakEnglish">I speak english</label><input type="checkbox" id="speakEnglish" name="speakEnglish" value="1"  /></li>
        <li><label for="speakGerman">I speak german</label><input type="checkbox" id="speakGerman" name="speakGerman" value="1"  /></li>

        <fieldset class="instrument">
        <legend>What is your main Instrument?</legend>
        <div class="margin-div">
                    <input type="radio" name="mainInst" value="voice" /> Voice
                    <input type="radio" name="mainInst" value="guitar" /> Guitar
                    <input type="radio" name="mainInst" value="keys" /> Keys
                    <input type="radio" name="mainInst" value="bass" /> Bass
                    <input type="radio" name="mainInst" value="sax" /> Sax<br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="mainInst" value="trumpet" /> Trumpet
                    <input type="radio" name="mainInst" value="percussion" /> Percussion
                    <input type="radio" name="mainInst" value="flute" /> Flute
                    <input type="radio" name="mainInst" value="other" /> Other
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="inspiration">
                <legend>Inspiration (list up to 5 musicians that inspire you)</legend>

                <ul>
                <li><label for="inspiration">Inspration</label>
                    <ul>
                    <li><input type="text" id="inspiration" name="inspiration1" /></li>
                    <li><input type="text" id="inspiration" name="inspiration2" /></li>
                    <li><input type="text" id="inspiration" name="inspiration3" /></li>
                    <li><input type="text" id="inspiration" name="inspiration4" /></li>
                    <li><input type="text" id="inspiration" name="inspiration5" /></li></ul>
               </li>
                </ul>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="margin-div"><textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="desc_long" class="required">Longer description</textarea></div>
    </fieldset><!-- /fieldset moreinfo -->



    <fieldset class="otherInfo">
    <legend>Other Info</legend>

        <fieldset class="links">
            <legend>More of me - If you would like we can include up to 3 links where people can see or hear more of you</legend>
            <ul>
                <li><label for="link1name">Name of Link 1</label><input type="text" id="link1name" name="link1name" value="Name of Link ( ex: My Band on Youtubr )" /></li>         
                <li><label for="link1url">URL of Link 1</label><input type="text" id="link1url" name="link1url" value="URL of Link ( ex: www.youtube.com?feature=dddkshue )"/></li>
                <li><label for="link2name">Name of Link 2</label><input type="text" id="link2name" name="link2name" /></li>
                <li><label for="link2url">URL of Link 2</label><input type="text" id="link2url" name="link2url" /></li>
                <li><label for="link3name">Name of Link 3</label><input type="text" id="link3name" name="link3name"  /></li>
                <li><label for="link3url">URL of Link 1</label><input type="text" id="link3url" name="link3url" /></li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="other">
            <legend>Other Information</legend>

            <ul>
                <li><label for="proExperience">Would you consider yourself a professional musician?</label><input type="checkbox" id="proExperience" name="proExperience" value="1"  /></li>
                <li><label for="haveStudio">Do you have your own recording facilities?</label><input type="checkbox" id="haveStudio" name="haveStudio" value="1" /></li>
                <li><label for="musicTheory">Do you know music theory?</label><input type="checkbox" id="musicTheory" name="musicTheory" value="1"  /></li>
                <li><label for="composer">Do you write your own music?</label><input type="checkbox" id="composer" name="composer" value="1"  /></li>
                <li><label for="teacher">Do you teach?</label><input type="checkbox" id="teacher" name="teacher" value="1"  /></li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>



        <fieldset class="contact">
            <legend>Contact Information</legend>
            <span><label for="email">Email Address</label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></span>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>  <!-- /more info -->
    <input type="hidden" name="thumb_image_location" value="<?php echo $thumb_image_location ?>" id="thumb_image_location" />
    <input type="hidden" name="large_image_location" value="<?php echo $large_image_location ?>" id="large_image_location" />

    <input type="submit" name="upload_thumbnail" value="Save Info" id="save_thumb" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have a `<div>` stretching over your fields but with a different z-index. That would prevent you from reaching the fields that are under the `<div>`

Comment: Most likely it's something like this. If you have Chrome or Safari (or Firebug installed in Firefox), try right-clicking on one of the inputs and "inspect element" and see what element is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that you have a disabled="disabled" attributes on the form field.

Code examples would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently...   and that was because I had form elements that were floating, which caused them to be outside the scope of the containing div when I clicked on them.

Taking the solution from [Keeping an floated image inside the div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369448/keeping-an-floated-image-inside-the-div-with-css) fixed my problem, and might fix yours.   In short:  Use overflow:hidden in your containing div.